# WP Super Cache unable to locate cache file for only the homepage

Tags: htaccess

I have WP Super Cache working perfectly on all pages of my blog except for the homepage. I'm using the PHP caching method (mod-rewrite is not compatible with my specific configuration with suPHP).

I've monitored the debug log and cache folder and can see *that the cache file is created successfully*, but when its reloaded wp-super-cache cannot find it and recreates it. A big clue seem to be that if I load the index.php file directly it works i.e.

www.site.com/blog/ <--- **Cannot find cache file**

www.site.com/blog/index.php <--- **Able to find cache file (caching works!)**

Im using the following permalink structure;

**www.site.com/blog/%postname%**

The .htaccess file is standard for the permalink structure

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm using the following DirectoryIndex directive in my virtual machine config.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

I've tried everything I can think of to resolve this including using the inotify package to monitor real-time file system activity to see what file name its looking for but it didn't help. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the path in your .htaccess rules matches where the supercache directory is. You may have to hardcode it. Or use the plugin in PHP or legacy caching mode.

Comment: I am using it in PHP mode as I said in the first sentence.Thanks.